# Difference between a string and Text

Tags: html, string

So in this practice it asks me to create a  in the html containing (in order): the string "Result" (no quotes) followed by a  tag with id "result" (no quotes).

What I would think of doing is this:

```
<div id="result"> Result </div>
```

But since it asked me to do them both in order (meaning the text "Result" should come first within the syntax and then the id) I started to ask myself whether a text can be considered a string?

is my example perfectly alright? is the "Result" within the Div a string? or is there a distinction? Also Am i allowed to put the id into the closing tag? And am i actually following the question correctly? I have no idea. So I would love it if someone can read what is asked and create the "" that they think is being asked?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, "Result" can be considered a string. It is just plain text, with no meaning (code) attached to it.

But you don't really use string types in HTML, but more in other true scripting languages such as JS, PHP, or Java, and in those languages you would usually have to escape it with quotes (`"` or `'`).

And your example is correct. Attributes (such as `id`) can only be placed in the first, opening tag.